# how do I implement browser-sync proxy to my gulpfile?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, browser-sync

after reading alot and trying to make my own gulpfile.js I figured out how to make it compile my "scss" to a "css", the problem is that my browser-sync doesn't work because I need a proxy (because im using .php not .html), If I write this on CMD: "browser-sync start --proxy localhost:8080/app" I can see my files, but I need it to sync every time I modify something on my "scss". All I need now is to implement the proxy thing on it and reloads everytime I save/modify the ".scss",  this is my currently gulpfile.js :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var paths = {
  scss: '.sass/*.scss'
};
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('scss/style.scss')
  .pipe(sass({
    includePaths: ['scss']
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});


gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  browserSync.init(["css/*.css", "js/*.js"], {
    server: {
      baseDir: "./"
    }
  });
});


gulp.task('watch', ['sass', 'browser-sync'], function () {
  gulp.watch(["scss/*.scss", "scss/base/*.scss", "scss/sections/*.scss", "scss/style/*.scss"], ['sass']);

});
```

This gulpfile.js is watching my "scss/syle.scss" and updates my "css/style.css" everytime I modify the scss file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the browserSync options? [This](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-proxy) should give you a pretty good idea on how to set it up. It doesn't seem like you implemented it in the gulpfile you provided.